# paypal is not defined in paypal.Buttons.driver("react", { React, ReactDOM });

Tags: reactjs, paypal

I want to develop a PayPal button, and following the API documentation, I have the following code:

```
import React, {useState}from 'react';
import {useDispatch} from 'react-redux';
import {useHistory} from 'react-router-dom';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import * as actionsReservations from '../../reservation/actions';
import {Errors} from '..';

const PayPalButton = paypal.Buttons.driver("react", { React, ReactDOM });

const PayPalReserve = ({deposit, menu, companyId, reservationDate, periodType, diners}) => {

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const history = useHistory();                                                                                                                                                                     
    const [backendErrors, setBackendErrors] = useState(null);

    const createOrder = (data,actions) => {
        return actions.order.create({
            purchase_units:[
                {
                    amount:{
                        value: deposit
                    },
                },
            ],
        });
    };

    const onApprove = (data, actions) => {
        return actions.order.capture().then(response => {
            dispatch(actionsReservations.reservation(
                menu.id,
                companyId,
                reservationDate,
                periodType,
                diners,
                response.id,
                () => history.push('/reservation/reservation-completed'),
                errors => setBackendErrors(errors)
            ));
            console.log(response);
        });
      }
};

export default PayPalReserve;
```

But is throwing me the following error:

```
Line 9:22:  'paypal' is not defined  no-undef
```

But if I import paypal from `paypal-checkout` with this line:

```
import paypal from 'paypal-checkout';
```

React throw me the following error:

```
"TypeError: paypal_checkout__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4___default.a.Buttons is undefined"
```

My index.html i have this in head tag:

```
<script defer src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=MY_CLIENT_CODE"></script>
```

I dont know why is throwing me these errors when i don't import paypal-checkout or when I import it. If you knew how to solve it, I would appreciate it

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Things will probably become easier for you if you simply use the official `react-paypal-js` package.

[Here is the storybook](https://paypal.github.io/react-paypal-js/?path=/docs/example-paypalbuttons--default) .. copying its example:

```
import { PayPalScriptProvider, PayPalButtons } from "@paypal/react-paypal-js";

<PayPalScriptProvider options={{ "client-id": "test" }}>
   <PayPalButtons
       style={{ layout: "horizontal" }}
       createOrder={(data, actions) => {
           return actions.order.create({
               purchase_units: [
                   {
                       amount: {
                           value: "2.00",
                       },
                   },
               ],
           });
       }}
   />;
</PayPalScriptProvider>
```

Answer (score 0):

That’s an eslint err, just add window at the beginning as PayPal is a global variable injected into the window obj

`console.log(window.paypal)`